# Does @property(retain) need a release?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Below are three fragments of code, the first two are interfaces for two objects along with a couple of @property commands. Please note that this is just me learning, its not part of an application just a small test program.

After adding (retain) to the 2nd @property I noticed that my machine object was leaking when my program exited, what I did to fix this was add a release in the Artist objects dealloc, does this sound right?

```
@interface Machine : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *type;
    NSString *os;
}

@interface Artist : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    Machine *system;
}
@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property(retain) Machine *system;
@end

// DEALLOC IN @implementation Artist
-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"_deal: %@", self);
    [system release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must call release by hands for each time you've called retain or alloc method.

Comment: Thank you, I know that "alloc" "new" "copy" and retain that you are responsible for relinquishing ownership of object. I was just not sure is retain in this situation followed the same rule, obviously it does.

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting Mac OS X, the best answer would be to turn on garbage collection and  delete the -dealloc method.

To answer the specific question, you need to `release` both `name` and `system` in your `-dealloc` method.

Comment: So as far as name goes the "release" in dealloc is to release the copy made in @property(copy).

Comment: Exactly;  `(copy)` and `(retain)` properties imply a `-retain` on set which needs to be balanced by a `-release` in `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by setting it to nil or calling release depending on OS.

Comment: You mean “depending on whether GC is turned on”. You can have GC turned off (and therefore need to release it) on either OS.