# How is release handled for @synthesized retain properties?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, memory-management, properties

I have some questions about synthesized properties in Objective-C. The full list follows, but the basic question is this: **How does the compiler ensure that the ivars for synthesized properties are properly released, even though my code may or may not include release methods in dealloc?**

Note: I decided not to post these as individual questions because they are so closely related and because there are a handful of existing questions that *touch* on the individual issues without really getting to the heart of the matter.

Somewhat similar questions:

- [Does property retain need a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782893/does-propertyretain-need-a-release)
- [What's the difference between property and synthesize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806379/whats-the-difference-between-property-and-synthesize)
- [Question on retain attribute with property and synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980488/question-on-retain-attribute-with-property-and-synthesize)

---

**Setup:** Consider a class with a single property:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString * name;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) name;
@end
```

---

**Question #1:** The very basic case:

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
@end
```

With this setup, I assume that `name` will be automatically released whenever a `Person` object is released. In my mind, the compiler simply inserts `[name release]` into the `dealloc` method as if I had typed it myself. Is that correct?

---

**Question #2:** If I choose to write my own `dealloc` method for this class, and I omit a call to `[name release]`, will that leak?

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
- (void)dealloc { [super dealloc]; }
@end
```

---

**Question #3:** If I choose to write my own `dealloc` method for this class, and I *include* a call to `[name release]`, will that result in a double-release, since `@synthesize` has already taken care of it for me?

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
- (void)dealloc { [name release]; [super dealloc]; }
@end
```

---

**Question #4:** If I choose to write my own property accessor for this class, but I *do not* write my own `dealloc` method, will `name` be leaked?

```
@implementation Person
@dynamic name;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [newName retain];
    [name release];
    name = newName;
}
@end
```

---

**Question #5:** I have a feeling (based on experience) that *none* of the above scenarios will result in leaks or double-releases, since the language has been designed to avoid them. That, of course, raises the question of "how?". Is the compiler simply smart enough to keep track of every possible case? What if I were to do the following (note that this is a ludicrous example, just meant to illustrate my point):

```
void Cleanup(id object) { [object release]; }

@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
- (void)dealloc { Cleanup(name); }
@end
```

Would that fool the compiler into adding another `[name release]` to the `dealloc` method?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Q1:**

No. `@synthesize` does not modify the `-dealloc` for you. You have to `-release` the `name` yourself.

**Q2:**

Yes it will leak. Same reason as Q1.

**Q3:**

No it won't double-release. Same reason as Q1.

**Q4:**

Yes it will leak. Same reason as Q1.

**Q5:**

No it won't double-release. Same reason as Q1.

---

You can check this yourself by overriding `-retain` and `-release` and `-dealloc` to report what is going on.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface X : NSObject {}
@end
@implementation X
-(oneway void)release {
        NSLog(@"Releasing %p, next count = %d", self, [self retainCount]-1);
        [super release];
}
-(id)retain {
        NSLog(@"Retaining %p, next count = %d", self, [self retainCount]+1);
        return [super retain];
}
-(void)dealloc {
        NSLog(@"Dealloc %p", self);
        [super dealloc];
}
@end

@interface Y : NSObject {
        X* x;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) X* x;
@end
@implementation Y
@synthesize x;
- (void)dealloc { [x release]; [super dealloc]; }
@end

int main () {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        Y* y = [[Y alloc] init];
        X* x = [[X alloc] init];
        y.x = x;
        [y release];
        [x release];
        [pool drain];                                                    
        return 0;
}
```

In Q1, Q2 and Q4, the last `-retainCount` of `x` is 1, so there is a leak, and in Q3 and Q5 the last `-retainCount` is 0 and `-dealloc` is called, so there is no leak.

Answer (score 17):

From the [Objective-C documentation on properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW16):

> dealloc
>
> Declared properties fundamentally take
>   the place of accessor method
>   declarations; when you synthesize a
>   property, the compiler only creates
>   any absent accessor methods. There is
>   no direct interaction with the dealloc
>   method—properties are not
>   automatically released for you.
>   Declared properties do, however,
>   provide a useful way to cross-check
>   the implementation of your dealloc
>   method: you can look for all the
>   property declarations in your header
>   file and make sure that object
>   properties not marked assign are
>   released, and those marked assign are
>   not released.

This essentially answers all your questions.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the link. That certainly gets to the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 8):

The simple and general rule: if you allocate, retain, or copy an object, YOU have to release it.

When you use the `retain` setter semantic setting in a `@synthesize` statement, you're asking the compiler to build for you a setter that calls `retain` on the object. Nothing more, nothing less. And since you are retaining that object (even though it's via magically auto-generated code), you have to release it, and where to release it is in `-(void)dealloc`.

Comment: +1 That is an excellent (and oft-referenced) rule. Many people (myself included, back when I asked this question) don't realize that specifying "retain" or "copy" in a property declaration still qualifies. I think the problem lies in the wording: "Did *I* retain the value? No, the compiler's automagic code did it for me. Oops."

Comment: A few months after posting this answer, I posted an even better one, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122786/iphone-objective-c-should-this-value-be-released/5122821#5122821

It has a good mnemonic in it. Go see.

Comment: Of course, it's obsoleted entirely by automatic reference counting. But for now, it's still how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Something else it's worth knowing - if you have a synthesised property, setting that property to nil (using dot syntax, of course) will release the ivar for you.