# release everything you have an @property retain @synthesize for?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I started banging away on my app and have gotten way deep and it is running great but I think I let some stuff run a little wild.

For every @property (nonatomic, retain) that then I create an @synthesize for I need to have [variable release] in the dealloc method - is this correct?

Even if it is an IBOutlet?

Comment: thanks guys, I think it finally made it through my thick skull

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  You declared ownership of the object by making it a `retain` property, which means you must relinquish ownership by releasing it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties

Comment: thanks, my first program and I just so so off track - have a ton of properties to release :)

Comment: you might want to check out Accessorizer...it'll make your life easier. http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html

Comment: as a related comment why am I seeing code now where people are setting their properties to nil instead of release? self.property = nil;

Comment: @Slee it's a common way to have the synthesized method do the releasing for you, but it has some subtle gotchas and caveats.  Search the site for "using accessors in dealloc" (or something along those lines)

Answer (score 4):

In addition, if you have a retained `IBOutlet`, you should release it and set it to `nil` in `-viewDidUnload`. That lets the object release its outlets when the view is removed, particularly in response to a low memory warning. By setting the ivar to `nil` in that method, you avoid the risk of double-releasing the ivar if the object is subsequently deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you retain the property you are responsible for releasing it.

> Declared properties fundamentally take the place of accessor method declarations; when you synthesize a property, the compiler only creates any absent accessor methods. There is no direct interaction with the dealloc method—properties are not automatically released for you.

[Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)

Typically you will do this in your dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [property release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```