# iPhone - self dismissing a viewController

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller that was presented using

```
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

this VC has several declared retained properties (@property) that I have to release on its dealloc.

The variables are declared as

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) myClass1 *myProperty;
@property (nonatomic,retain) myClass2 *myProperty2;
// etc... and then synthesized on .m
```

The problem is that when I dismiss the viewController using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it crashes on the dealloc, when releasing the retained properties I have declared, with the error **modifying layer that is being finalized **

Apparently the the viewController is gone at the time its own dealloc runs and then it crashes.

How do I solve that? Thanks in advance.

### edit

the code that presents the viewController is on the rootViewController and is this:

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
myVC.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];

[self presentModalViewController:navigator animated:YES];
[navigator release];
[myVC release];
```

and this is the what the dealloc code on myVC contains

```
- (void) dealloc {
  [myProperty1 release]; // see this properties at the beginning of this question
  [myProperty1 release]; // if I comment these 2 relesases it stops crashing
  [super dealloc];
}
```

myVC is dismissed from inside itself, but that's fine according to the docs. I have also tried to dismiss it from the rootviewController but it continues to crash. The only way to stop crashing is to disable the release lines on the dealloc.

Comment: Can you post dealloc code. Looks like you are releasing the view controller instance which was not retained.

Comment: Can you post come code.  What you're doing should work.  You have another wrinkle posing a problem.  Post the dealloc and the method that presents the view controller.  Something may be up with your view.

Comment: post the dealloc method in myVC, but also the code that you use to allocate/init myProperty and myProperty2...

Comment: the code where I allocate myProperty is at the beginning of the question... I have added the code where I create and present myVC and dealloc it.

Comment: ah... I do something like this: UIView *oneView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];  self.myProperty1 = oneView;    [oneView release];

Comment: What happened to your problem? Solved?

Comment: nope. Still trying to figure it out. Thanks anyway. I think the problem is related to xcode. There's some sort of problem in the source files. I am transposing the whole project to a new clean template and I think it will work. I will post the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you set the properties?

```
self.myProperty =
```

? My guess is that you do not retain them. Are you doing

```
myProperty = ...
```

by any chance, with neither a retain or self.? The setter you synthesize needs a chance to actually retain your newly created object...

So in full it should read something like this:

```
MyClass1 *aProperty = [[MyClass1 alloc] init];
self.myProperty1 = aProperty;
[aProperty release];
```

Comment: ah... I do something like this: UIView *oneView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];  self.myProperty1 = oneView;    [oneView release];  ... more or less exactly what you have at the end of your answer.

Comment: I think it would be best if you posted all of your code in this class. Otherwise we are just guessing :)

Comment: this answer of yours made me find the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

...i asked where you allocate and init "myProperty1" and "myProperty2"...

i'm afraid that you make confusion thinking that this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) myClass1 *myProperty;
@property (nonatomic,retain) myClass2 *myProperty2;
```

need that you release myProperty and myProperty2

well, you are wrong!

you are just declaring the kind of objects you are going to use, not allocating them

you need to release them just if you alloc them someWhere...

Comment: this is not the docs I have been reading say. They say you have to release anything declared as retain or copy on @property, because the setter will retain the property. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties

Comment: the problem may be that you didn't put anything in myClass when you release them in dealloc. with @property (nonatomic,retain) myClass1 *myProperty; and @synthesize myClass1; you create automatic method to set and get value for myClass, but then you have to call them, with self.myClass1 = (someValue)... and the setter will retain myClass for you, then you can release it when you dealloc "self", but if for some reason "dealloc" is called when myObject is still empty (=nil) it's an error... you may try to add this check: if (myClass!=nil) {[myClass release]}