# Should this value be released?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I was getting a segfault 11 memory access error in the IOS Simulator, but it disappears when I comment out the release in the code below.

```
// get get the question number
NSString *text = [attributeDict valueForKey:XML_TAG_QUESTION_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER];
question.number = [text intValue];
//[text release]; <==== no more segfault 11 when this is commented out.
```

My question is, since I am receiving an instance of NS String returned by the `NSXMLParser` implementation, isn't the reference count increased and should I not be releasing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the rule: Always NARC on your memory management.

If you call:
(N)ew
(A)lloc
(R)etain or
(C)opy...

You need to release. If not, you got it through a convenience method and it's autoreleased.

In the case of containers of other objects, the container has the objects retained, and you don't need to worry about it until you release the container.

Comment: Great way to remember, I've never heard it that way! :)

Answer (score 2):

No it should not.

Read the memory management programming guide : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html