# Are synthesized properties automatically released in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is release handled for @synthesized retain properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties)

I saw someone mention somewhere (I don't remember who or where) that properties that are synthesized are automatically set to nil in dealloc and hence released. However Instruments thinks different by just marking everything as memory leaks.
Which one is correct? Maybe I missed a feature that makes this happen? (this is definitely not arc as I saw it about the time iOS 4.1 was out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [How is release handled for @synthesized retain properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties)

So pretty much you have to release it yourself. It does not do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't. You must release it on dealloc.

If the property is configured with the `retain` option, whenever its setter is called, it will receive a `retain` message, consequently needing a future `release`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC and your ivars are objective-c objects then they are released for you :)

example:

```
@interface Car : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *modelName;
@property (nonatomic) char *moreInfo;
@end

@implementation Car
@synthesize modeName;
@synthesize moreInfo;
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        moreInfo = (char *)malloc(128*sizeof(char)); // malloc'ed, 
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc{
    free(moreInfo); // malloc'ed vars are not automatically released
    //[modelName release]; // Since we are using ARC this is provided by the compiler 
    //[super dealloc]; // Since we are using ARC this is provided by the compiler 
}
```

@end