# Alloc a new objective C object to a retained property?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retaincount, alloc

Sorry for asking a totally basic question, but if I have a synthesized property that is retained.

```
 self.myProperty = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

will cause a memory leak?

So am I correct in thinking that I need to do

```
self.myProperty = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[self.myProperty release];
```

in order to balance? Because that seems dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard practice would be to use `autorelease` in that situation. So:

```
self.myProperty = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This is because `init` returns a retained object, and since your property also retains it, you'll have to release it.

Edited to add: @walkytalky makes a good point in the comments that it is actually `alloc` that retains the object, `init` just returns it.

Comment: Note that, conceptually, the retain comes from `alloc`. Of course, since `init` subsequently returns the object, what you say is also true. And indeed there might be cases where `init` returns a *different* retained object, but still, tradition associates the retain with allocation rather than initialisation (as in the old NARC rule).

Answer (score 0):

With ARC enabled, xcode will handle alle the memory management.
When not using ARC be sure to release it in the dealloc method.

Comment: So I don't need to release after alloc I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: You should release it in dealloc, not dealloc. Generally you should never call dealloc yourself, the notable exception being `[super dealloc]` when you are currently deallocing something.

Comment: If you do manual memory management, you typically delete all objects in the dealloc method. There are some documents of Apple out there which I really recommend!! Especially the "transfer of ownership" is really something you should know.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties) that you will find helpful.

You are correct. Without ARC, any property that is retained needs to be released as well.

You can also do:

```
self.myProperty = nil;
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> **retain**
>
> Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon
> assignment.
>
> The previous value is sent a release message.

Comment: `self.myProperty = nil` does not address the problem -- it will only undo the retain done by the property itself, leaving the one from `alloc` dangling with no way to release it.

Comment: @walkytalky when you call self.myProperty = nil, [myProperty release] is called from the synthesized setter, so why would that leave anything extra dangling vs. calling [myProperty release]?

Comment: Reread the question. The issue is the unbalanced ownership lien granted by `alloc`. Calling `[myProperty release]` releases *that*, without resetting the property value. The property's ownership semantics are then correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another (more verbose) technique is to do:

```
NSObject *o = [[NSObject alloc] init]; //retain count 1
self.myProperty = o;                   //retain count 2
[o release];                           //retain count 1
```

Personally though, I'd probably just use autorelease as in the first example above.