# Memory Managment Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have the Header of this class in my project:

```
    @interface VideoItem : NSObject <NSCoding> {
        NSString *idStr;
        NSString *name;
        NSString *link;
    }

    -(id)initWithVideoItem:(VideoItem*)video;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *link;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *idStr;

    @end
```

this is the implement:

```
@implementation VideoItem
@synthesize name,link,idStr;

-(id)initWithVideoItem:(VideoItem*)video{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = video.name;
        self.link = video.link;
        self.idStr = video.idStr;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark 
#pragma mark NSCoder

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"video_name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.link forKey:@"video_link"];  
    [encoder encodeObject:self.idStr forKey:@"video_id"];   
    [encoder encodeObject:self.imgUrl forKey:@"video_img"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.viewCount forKey:@"video_views"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.artist forKey:@"video_artist"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.timeStr forKey:@"video_timestr"];    
    [encoder encodeInt:self.seconds forKey:@"video_secondes"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.rating forKey:@"video_rating"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"video_name"];
        self.link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"video_link"]; 
        self.idStr = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"video_id"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And i want to know if in case like this i need to add `dealloc` method and release the strings or not?

Comment: in that case you must implement a dealloc method, as suggested in the answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189919/how-is-release-handled-for-synthesized-retain-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should release the strings because when using the properties that retain objects.

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [idStr release];
   [name release];
   [link release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Normally you would copy the object in the init, this is a better way then since the orginal object can then savely be edited or released.

```
-(id)initWithVideoItem:(VideoItem*)video{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        name = [video.name copy];
        link = [video.link copy];
        idStr = [video.idStr copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Since the `copy` method return a retained object you want to skip the property, since that would increase the retain count.

On a other note: the objective-c convention the private ivar should start with an `_` to make it more obvious that they are not properties.

Comment: And what the copy method will do? what is the different between them?

Comment: Copy makes a copy of the original object, your code uses the same object. Thus if the original object gets changed so thus the property in the object you create with the `initWithVideoItem:`. Thus making an copy make sure that you are not revering to the other object.

Answer (score 1):

Use ARC and forget any problems related to memory management.
Even apple encourages using ARC whenever possible. If you are doing this as a new development, I would recommend you to use ARC.

In case you do not want to use ARC, you need to implement dealloc and release your member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are retaining your string properties.
So it's your task to release it.

So add a `dealloc` method and release them.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [idStr release];
   [name release];
   [link release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, release all your allocated variables and at last call super dealloc :

```
- (void)dealloc{
   [idStr release];
   [name release];
   [link release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write
- (void)dealloc
Method as you are retaining the variable's. and release these variables in this method.

Answer (score -1):

In fact you need not call the release on the ivars. Instead use the properties 
self.ivar = nil. This releases your memory and sets the pointes to nil as a result of it there are no dangling pointers.

if you use [ivar release], ivar is released but is a dangling pointer, so most of the time ivar = nil; is done after releasing the ivar.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   self.idStr = nil;
   self.name = nil;
   self.link = nil;

   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: There are two places where you shouldn't be using `self.` One is in initialiser methods, and the other is the `dealloc`. It might be okay in this case, but if any of them are lazily loaded, you'll be instantiating them to set them to nil.

Comment: `[_iVar release], _iVar = nil;` is correct with MRC, with ARC, you don't need to release or nil anything in `dealloc`