# Why shouldn't I release when assigning to a retain property?

Tags: objective-c, retaincount

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782893/does-propertyretain-need-a-release), but simpler. [I think I may be close to the end of these dumb questions and can get down to serious business :)].

I have a `retain` property and set to it like this:

```
UINavigationController *thing = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:one];
    // thing's retain count is one
navController = thing;
    // thing's retain count is still one!
[thing release];
    // now retain count is zero, which is wrong
```

I cannot understand why the retain count gets to zero. `navController` is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
```

**Shouldn't the property increase the retain count by one?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is: you are assigning directly to the property's underlying instance variable instead of calling the setter. The property magic is not triggered this way. Try

```
self.navController = thing;
```

instead (remaining code needs no change).

Comment: Cool, now I can finally do this `self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:one] autorelease];` which is what I was going for. Thanks again.